# AS3 undefined function #1006

Tags: actionscript-3, import

I have a parent class called 'main.as'. I am trying to get the child class to call main's function. They both reside in the same folder.

```
// main.as //
package {

  public class main extends MovieClip {

    public function main() {
      var child:child_mc = new child_mc(this);
    }

    public function callFunction():void {
      trace("Done it");
    }

  }
}
```

.

```
// child.as //
package {
  import main;

  public class child extends MovieClip {

    private var main:MovieClip = new MovieClip();

    public function child(main:MovieClip):void {
      this.main = main;
      main.callFunction();
    }

  }
}
```

This is the error I've been getting:

```
TypeError: Error #1006: callFunction is not a function.
```

so I tried doing a trace like this

```
trace(main.callFunction);
```

and it says undefined. Can someone tell me what I am missing. I get this feeling its a very basic thing that I have overlooked!

Comment: Seems like you don't need `import main;` , try to remove it

Comment: I am still getting the same error. I thought importing it would help recognise the function.

Comment: So may be show us a more of your codes ? Classes definitions and so on

Comment: I have made the changes. child_mc is a library MovieClip btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "child" package is defined as "main". I'm not even sure how it complied, let alone run to the point of showing the error message you got.

I believe the code below should do what you expected.

*(I also took the liberty to rename the classes to use [CamelCase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) (with initial caps) to adhere to best practices and to be easier to distinguish from variable names.)*

**Main.as**

```
package {

    public class Main extends MovieClip {

        public function Main() {
            var child:ChildMC = new ChildMC();
            child.main = this;
        }

        public function callFunction():void {
            trace("Done it");
        }

    }
}
```

**EDIT:** I just saw your comment that points out that `child_mc` is a MovieClip in the Library. I guess then that the `child` class is set as the Base Class of the `child_mc`?

If so, you cannot pass properties through the instantiator, you need to find another way to pass along the instance of the Main class to the Child class.

One way would be to add a *setter*, like the following:

**Child.as** *(Base Class for ChildMC)*

```
package {

    public class Child extends MovieClip {

        private var _main:Main;

        public function Child() {

        }

        public function set main(main:Main):void {
            this._main = main;
            this._main.callFunction();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Updated answer in light of seeing that the `child_mc` is a Library MovieClip.

Comment: Yes, it was a typo. i was changing all my class names as it was long and complicated, and i wanted this to be easier to read. thanks for the help!